# What’s the place called where the lord/ ruler of a village in the 1400s lived?

Tags: single-word-requests

In England in the 1400s, most people had a small house but where the lord would live was different, bigger. In particular, in Skyrim the Jarls live in keeps but that's a little too big for what I’m looking for.

Comment: While you might use the answers to this question in writing, the question itself has nothing to do with writing. I've flagged it as needing to be migrated to History SE.

Comment: Keeps don't have to be as large as the castles in Skyrim.

Comment: The big house.  Of course that's also where the *former* lord and ruler of the local crime mob lived about 500 years later.

Answer (score 11):

My guess would be [Manor](https://www.etymonline.com/word/manor): From the link;

> late 13c., "mansion, habitation, country residence, principal house of an estate," from Anglo-French *maner*, Old French *manoir* "abode, home, dwelling place; manor" (12c.).

Answer (score 1):

In the Middle Ages, the building was called a "manor house".

Comment: This would be a better answer if you identified a source.